# Pass data to component's textarea in vue.js 2.0

Tags: vue.js

I have a modal component with textarea which I use to edit `data` that's in my main instance. So the idea is when I open the modal component, the textarea should be showing current `data` value from the main instance, this can be done by passing `data` as prop to the modal component. But since it's prop, vue doesn't allow me to edit it in textarea.  And if I use `v-model` for the textarea, how do I get the original `data` value the moment my modal popup?

Back in 1.x, I just need to add "two-way: true", but this approach depreciated in 2.0.

Comment: does it work if you pass an object containing the text property to the prop (instead of a plain text)?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, the textarea attribute is like this                 `<textarea  v-model="cellModel"></textarea>` how do you put an object as `v-model` ?

Comment: I was meaning: pass `myProp` object as a prop and on the text area you pass `v-model="myProp.cellModel"`. not sure

Comment: You are absolutely genius, works like a charm!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: cool I make it as an answer so you can mark it as sloved : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass myProp object as a prop and on the text area you pass v-model="myProp.cellModel"

Comment: I don't think this is hacky. This is the way javascript works: copied object are just references. But if you want to handle your state without passing properties all over, check vuex. This will clean up everything.

Comment: right, I said hacky in the sense that we are modiying props where vue discourage that.